# LOCK TABLE as a prepared statement?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking, prepared-statement

Does it make sense to prepare a LOCK TABLE statement?  I'm not really concerned about efficiency here, because it would only execute once a transaction and at most a few times a minute.  I'm more wondering if the concept is meaningful.

I'm using the PostgreSQL JDBC driver, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance aside, preparing statements is useful when you have parameters in your query. Since your query has no parameters you don't need to prepare it.

Comment: Yeah, standard practice here is to use prepared statements for everything, but I guess it would be taking that too far in this case.  Thanks.